# PHP open_basedir restriction in effect, but file is actually within the allowed path

Tags: php, plesk, include-path, open-basedir

I've looked at questions (and answers) about **openbase_dir** where the required or included file was outside the allowed path(s). I've looked at all the suggested similar questions while editing this one, but I didn't find a case like mine.

I'm using **Plesk 12.5** on a **CentOS** VPS.

I have a `maindomain.com` with a `subdomain.maindomain.com` and also `otherdomain1.com`, `otherdomain2.com`, `otherdomain3.com` and so on.

I need to access some files located in `/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com` from all `otherdomains.com`.

In my case I've included in both open_basedir

```
.:/opt/plesk/php/7.0/share/pear:/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com
```

and **include_path**

```
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}:/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com/
```

the exact path where I need to look into, but I still get the error:

```
Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com/filename.php) is not within the allowed path(s): 
(/var/www/vhosts/otherdomain.com/:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com) 
in /var/www/vhosts/otherdomain.com/httpdocs/index.php on line XXX

Warning: require_once(/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com/filename.php): failed to open stream: 
Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/otherdomain.com/httpdocs/index.php on line XXX

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com/filename.php' 
(include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.0/share/pear:/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com') 
in /var/www/vhosts/otherdomain.com/httpdocs/index.php on line XXX
```

**Summarizing...**

I can't access `/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com/filename.php` from `/var/www/vhosts/otherdomain.com/httpdocs/index.php` while this path `/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com` is in both `open_basedir` and `include_path`.

What else am I missing?

Anyone had the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: maybe it's a behavior of the dot in `open_basedir`

Comment: @Deadooshka thanks for commenting. Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: I always add a trailing slash to `open_basedir` directories, due to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). The dot means a current directory that changable with `chdir()` inside a script.

Comment: I tried both with trailing slash and without. There is no dot in the path. I also tried configuring only open_basedir or only include_path, then both. Still not working.

Comment: What are permissions and ownership of the /var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/subdomain.maindomain.com directory?